# Explanation needed for different ways of calculating precision (ISO-5725 and CLSI EP05-A2)

Tags: precision, repeatability, reproducibility

I'm trying to get along with calculating precision of analytical method.
I'm a chemist not a mathematician.

ICH M10 guideline requires that:

> Accuracy and precision should be determined by analysing the QCs within each run (within-run) and in different runs (between-run).

Thus, it doesn't define how to do it.

In the previous laboratory I've worked I was doing it according to ISO-5725-2. But I haven't analysed it in-depth.
In my current laboratory they do it in the way that is in my opinion not suitable.
I asked my boss to change this procedure but he requires me to explain in details every bit of this procedure (or simplified version from CLSI EP05-A2).

There is one part I don't understand, thus I ask for explanation.

NOTE:
There are two differences between those two guidelines that might be important to good explanation:

1. ISO-5725 is working on in-lab variance and between-lab variance where EP05 in-day variance and between-day
2. ISO-5725 allows to remove outliers thus series can have different numbers of measurement where EP05 assumes equal groups.

---

ad 1. I discussed it with some guys proficient in stats and the conclusion was that expanding from in-day to between-day is calculated the same as from in-lab to between-lab. Basic model: $S_R^2 =  S_r^2 + S_I^2$

where:

- $S_R^2$ - variance of reproducibility
- $S_r^2$ - variance of repeatability (in-day or in-lab)
- $S_I^2$ - intermediate variance (between-day or between-lab)

Given 3 series by 6 measurements, I assume that there are no differences in calculations if those series are separated by different reproducibility criterion (different day or different lab).

If I'm wrong here, please explain me why?

---

So, step by step, what I understand and what I don't.

A) Both guidelines have some obvious calculation that don't need explanation, like in-group variations, in-group means and overall mean.

---

B) AFAIU both guidelines calculate repeatability the same way with respect for the allowed difference in number of measurements.

For EP05 it is:

$$
S_r^2 = \frac {\sum_{d=1}^{D} \sum_{r=1}^{n} (x_{rd}-\overline{x_d})^2}{D(n-1)}
$$

where:

- $D$ - total number of days
- $n$ - total number of replicates per day
- $x_{dr}$ - result for replicate r on day d
- $\overline{x_d}$ - average of all replicates on day d

As I understand it is basic mean of each day variance.

For ISO it is:

$$
S_{r}^2 = \frac {\sum_{i=1}^{p} (n_{i}-1)S_{i}^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{p} (n_{i}-1)}
$$

where:

- $S_i^2$ - variance of measurement group i
- $n_i$ - total number of samples in group i
- $p$ - total number of groups

As I understand it is weighted mean of each day variance. If all groups have the same number of samples, it is the same as in EP05.

### The part where I'm bit lost and need explanation.

---

C) Intermediate precision and reproducibility from EP05.

The first step is to calculate the variance of the daily means:

$$
S_{d}^2 = \frac {\sum_{i=1}^{D} (\overline{x_d}- \overline{\overline{x}})^2}{D - 1}
$$

where:

- D - total number of days
- $\overline{x_d}$ - average of all replicates on day d
- $\overline{\overline{x}}$ average of all results

That is clear for me.

But after that there is something like this:

$$
S_{R}^2 = \frac {n-1}{n} × S_{r}^2 + S_{d}^2
$$
where:

- $n$ - total number of replicates per each day

It is clear for me why reproducibility variance is calculated as addition of repeatability variance and variance of means between days.

**But why there is $\frac {n-1}{n}$ in this formula?**

That is the part I don't understand in EP05

---

D) In ISO-5725 this part looks bit different. (And there is partiall explanation for $\frac {n-1}{n}$ from EP05)

Last sum $S_R^2 =  S_r^2 + S_I^2$ is as in the general model.
But:

$$
S_{I}^2 = \frac {S_{D}^2 - S_{r}^2} {\overline{\overline{n}}}
$$

where:
$$
\overline{\overline{n}} = \frac {\sum_{i=1}^{p} n_i - \frac {\sum_{i=1}^{p} n_{i}^2 }{\sum_{i=1}^{p} n_i}} {p -1}
$$

$\overline{\overline{n}}$ for all equal groups = n

Side question:
**What kind of weighting $\overline{\overline{n}}$ is? Do it have a name?**

and:

$$
S_{D}^2 = \frac {\sum_{i=1}^{p} n_i ( \overline {x_{i}} - \overline{\overline{x}}) ^2 } {p -1}
$$

$S_{D}^2$ is like variance of daily means but every squared deviation from overall mean is multiplied by respective number of measurements in this group.

If I understand properly, this together with $\overline{\overline{n}}$ it is for weighting variances of groups that have different measurements numbers.

If all groups are equal $S_{D}^2 = n × S_{d}^2$

So for eqal groups:

$$
S_{I}^2 = \frac {n × S_{d}^2 - S_{r}^2} {n} = S_{d}^2 - \frac {S_{r}^2} {n}
$$

and thus:

$$
S_{R}^2 = S_r^2 + S_I^2 =  S_r^2 + S_{d}^2 - \frac {S_{r}^2} {n} =\frac {n-1}{n} × S_{r}^2 + S_{d}^2
$$

So, forcing equal groups we get the same final formula as EP05.
I t doesn't help me much.
I can only rephrase my question as:
**Why repeatability is divided by n in $
S_{I}^2 = S_{d}^2 - \frac {S_{r}^2} {n}
$?**

I'll appreciate any help or directions where I can find answer

Radek